# strrchr() will only change the haystack and ignore the needle plus won't return anything

Tags: c, eclipse, string

I need to write a function which will get the base64 string from an Authorization Header in HTTP 1.0.  Therefore, I wrote this function:

```
char* getAuthenticate(char* buffer) {
    const char* AuthorizationLine = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    char* BasePtr;
    char* CodePtr = calloc(1, sizeof(char));

    //Get Authoriztaion Header
    if(strstr(buffer, "Authorization: ") != NULL) {
        AuthorizationLine = strstr(buffer, "Authorization: ");
        char Copy[strlen(AuthorizationLine)];
        strcpy(Copy, AuthorizationLine);
        AuthorizationLine = strtok(Copy, "\r\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Error - no valid Authorization Header");
        return NULL;
    }
    //Set CodePtr to the base64 String
    CodePtr = strrchr(AuthorizationLine, " ");
    CodePtr = CodePtr +1;
    return CodePtr;
}
```

By running this function in the debugger, I discovered that everything is fine until I get to the CodePtr Part. Once I perform `CodePtr = strstr(AuthorizationLine, " ")`, my authorization line will be filled with crap, for example  "\020Õÿÿÿ\177".  And the `CodePtr` is not even affected: its address stays `0x0` until I do `+1`, but then it's only `0x1` and Eclipse cannot access memory at that address.

So what did I do wrong? I also tried `strstr()`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: You mention `CodePtr = strstr(AuthorizationLine, " ")`. Do you mean `CodePtr = strrchr(AuthorizationLine, " ");`?

Comment: no, I mean that I also tried to resolve the header with the strstr function, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Why do you `calloc` a `char` for `CodePtr` and `AuthorizationLine`? The usual practice would be to initialize them to `NULL`. Anyway, your problem is that `Copy` is allocated in an inner scope but accessed outside of that scope through the `AuthorizationLine` pointer.

Comment: Don't really know why I calloc, it just worked fine most of the time so I kept it up. I'll try allocatin Copy outside that scope

Comment: You should also not forget to: `char Copy[strlen(AuthorizationLine)];` because you have to make space for the `'\0'` in your string.

Comment: `char* getAuthenticate(char* buffer) {
 char* AuthorizationLine = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
 char* BasePtr;
 char* CodePtr = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
 char Copy[150];

 //Lese den Authoriztaion Header ein
 if(strstr(buffer, "Authorization: ") != NULL) {
  AuthorizationLine = strstr(buffer, "Authorization: ");
//  char Copy[strlen(AuthorizationLine)];
  strcpy(Copy, AuthorizationLine);
  AuthorizationLine = strtok(Copy, "\r\n");
 }
 else {
  printf("Error - no valid Authorization Header");
  return NULL;
 }`

Comment: `void dataOut(char* user, char* pw) {
 printf("Credentials:\nUser: \t %s\n", user);
 printf("Password: \t %s", pw);
}`
This is the new code. It still does the same as the one in the question

Answer (score 2):

Your function leaks memory.  It allocates space for one `char` and assigns a pointer to that space to variable `AuthorizationLine`, but then later assigns a new value to `AuthorizationLine` without freeing the allocated memory.  You don't appear to need to allocate any memory here.

You do not declare array `Copy` large enough.  You need room for the string terminator, too.  You therefore get undefined behavior when you copy into that array.

You set `AuthorizationLine` to a pointer to part of array `Copy`, but that `Copy` goes out of scope immediately after, leaving `AuthorizationLine` an invalid pointer.

Very likely, `strrchr()` (or `strstr()`) then overwrites whatever memory `AuthorizationLine` points to (somewhere on the stack) with values of its local variables.  `strrchr()` returns a NULL pointer, because that's what it does when the specified character is not found.

Additionally, you return a pointer (in)to a local variable.  This presents the same kind of problem that occurs when `Copy` goes out of scope.

**Update:**

This version will do the trick.  Note that it returns a pointer to allocated memory, which the caller is obligated to free when it is no longer needed.

```
char* getAuthenticate(char* buffer) {
    /* Get Authoriztaion Header */
    const char* AuthorizationLine = strstr(buffer, "Authorization: ");

    if (AuthorizationLine) {
        /* extract the authorization token */
        char* EndPtr = strstr(AuthorizationLine, "\r\n");
        char* CodePtr;

        if (!EndPtr) {
            /* the header is the last thing in the buffer */
            EndPtr = AuthorizationLine + strlen(AuthorizationLine) - 1;
        }

        /* ignore trailing whitespace */
        while (isspace(*EndPtr)) {
            EndPtr -= 1;
        }
        /* find the start of the authorization token */
        for (CodePtr = EndPtr; !isspace(*CodePtr); CodePtr -= 1 ) {
             if (CodePtr == AuthorizationLine) {
                 printf("Error - invalid authorization header\n");
                 return NULL;
             }
        }            

        /* allocate space and copy the token into it */
        ptrdiff_t value_length = ++EndPtr - CodePtr++;
        char *Copy = malloc(value_length + 1);

        if (Copy) {
            strncpy(Copy, CodePtr, value_length);
            Copy[value_length] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Error - memory allocation failure\n");
        }
        return Copy;
    } else {
        printf("Error - no Authorization Header\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer *-*
Now I don't really know how to change all of that. I can free the variables and I can declare Copy as strlen(AuthorizationLine)+1. But I don't really know how I can make AuthorizationLine a valid Pointer =/

Comment: @HannahAround The first thing you have to decide is what exactly you want to return. You now return a `char*`, ie. a pointer to some memory. That memory must be allocated somewhere. You can use `malloc` for that, but that means that the caller of your function must free the memory.

Comment: That's OK. I want to return a char* and I already allocated the memory with `calloc(1, sizeof(char)`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a possible implementation.

Comment: Hey thanks =) it works very well ^^ I found other errors now, but this one works fine =3

Answer (score -1):

Sorry Hanna (I've read the previous comments)...

The problem you're having is your buffer size.  You (properly) used calloc but you have no null terminator.  Remember strcpy will read until a null terminator is found.  This is why you're getting "crap" in your buffer.  Additionally, your strtok isn't gonna work well off of 1 char. lol.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did ^.^ With strncat I put a \0 at the end of my AuthorizationLine and it doesn't get crappy any longer ^-^ Still, CodePtr won't get any Content D: